# How do you define a reference to a view in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I'm trying to run code from Chapter 5 "Android Application Development All-in-One for Dummies".

The code in the book refers directly to view Id's in an onButtonClick function

```
fun onButtonClick(view: View){
...
 
        if (checkBox.isChecked()){
            ...
        }
```

but Android Studio highlights checkBox as an unresolved reference.

**What I tried**

I tried changing

```
fun onButtonClick(view: View){
...
        val checkBox = view.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox)
        if (checkBox.isChecked()){
            ...
        }
```

but that crashed at runtime with checkBox is null.
I looked at [How can you add a reference to another view through attributes in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202903/how-can-you-add-a-reference-to-another-view-through-attributes-in-android) and tried changing

```
fun onButtonClick(view: View){
...
        val vp : ViewGroup = view.getParent()
        val checkBox = vp.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox)
        if (checkBox.isChecked()){
            ...
        }
```

but that got type mismatch: inferred type is ViewParent (which doesn't have findViewByID)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unresolved reference - activity does not recognize synthetic imports in android studio v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64716903/unresolved-reference-activity-does-not-recognize-synthetic-imports-in-android)

Comment: if you're in a fragment/activity, just use findViewById

Comment: `The code in the book refers directly to view Id's in an onButtonClick function` see the link i provided above. synthetic imports are deprecated and new projects don't have the import anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me write a complete answer

you say:

> The code in the book refers directly to view Id's in an onButtonClick
> function

These are synthetic imports for kotlin, but they're deprecated and new projects don't have these added by default anymore. so your alternative is either `ViewBinding` or `findViewById`

in your situation (without seeing your code)

i'm going to assume you *just* need `findViewById` and don't need a view reference, so you should be able to do:

```
fun onButtonClick(view: View){
...
    val checkBox = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox)
    if (checkBox.isChecked()){
        ...
    }
```

what happens in the following code:

```
fun onButtonClick(view: View) {
```

well, the view which has triggered onButtonClick is passed through, so in your case, if you're pressing a button, then the actual button is passed to you here, so if you use `view.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox)` you're trying to find your checkbox on the button itself, which doesn't work.

by just using `findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox)`, that's a reference to the root layout and your checkbox should then be found